# What security policies and practices could one practice to safegaurd against being inebriated?

Tags: password-policy, defense

My passwords for the most part as well as access procedures I could do while inebriated/intoxicated. Be it a simple login/password login to email or VPN and accessing a database.

This might sound weird but what can one do to help prevent access if one was inebriated via their own means or another person's means in order to get them to gain access?

I am not looking for practices and procedures for me (don't set up my intervention just yet!) but practices that could be applied to anyone not in a sound state of mind to prevent compromising a system they have access to.

Comment: Didn't Google implement math questions for something?

Comment: Have a policy of no drinking while working and no working while intoxicated.

Comment: What is it you're really trying to protect against? Being drunk or duress access?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is one good answer but here are some suggestions. You could utilize a captcha with extra visual artifacts or more characters than normal on every login. Perhaps a simple riddle or a bit of javascript that forces a user to click on targets with a time limit like [this](http://aim400kg.com/). I think the most feasible, reliable option would be requiring two-factor identification with a PIN from a phone app that will only be displayed on the phone if the user passes a breathalyzer test. Such [devices](http://techcrunch.com/2014/08/30/drinkmate/) do exist for Android and at least one option exists for [PC](http://www.breathalyzeralcoholtester.com/usb-pc-connect-kit-for-accucell.html) although I think a smartphone-based option is superior. Hopefully this helps or at least provides some additional ideas.